# Can't recover MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, terminal

I've spent the past week setting up a custom CMS using Rubies on Rails and MySQL, even with no previous experience with these tools everything seemed to go quite smoothly. Throughout this time I left my computer on and for the most part the local server stayed running in Terminal, but after turning it off for the weekend everything I worked on seems to have disappeared.

When trying to view a previously working page at `localhost:3000/access` I get an error saying
`Access denied for user 'berges_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I had a lot of trouble logging in to the root user and had to sift through Google searches to reset my password but now all I see is the below without the working databases I created called `berges_cms_development`

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

I ran into a few issues besides the faulty password before getting to this stage but due to my lack of knowledge with this stuff I really can't say what was going on.

I'm kind of freaking out now so any bit of advice would be great.

Comment: if you did not have any data in the database previously, run your migrations again and all your tables would come back

Comment: I had plenty of data. I had set up everything needed for admin users, and specific content fields for different page types and had them all linked to a working admin panel. if i ran the migrations would I lose all of that?

I guess I could be okay to lose the inputted content but it wouldn't ruin how everything is setup would it?

Comment: Just tried checking the migration status and I get `rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'berges_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: you need to update your `config/database.yml` file with the correct `username` and `password`

Comment: it has the right information in there, but thanks, this just lead me to remembering what was wrong earlier

I see it's setting the socket value to `/tmp/mysql.sock` which I kept getting errors about and I have not been able to manually find this file in its directory

Comment: I also have no `my.cnf` file